# call instance method from higher order component in react

Tags: reactjs

If I have a class like this that contains a `createDocument` method:

```
class Sine extends Component {
  createDocument() {
    console.log('in createDocument');
  }

  render(el, props) {
    return (
        <div className="row">
          <div className="row">
            <h1>Sine Wave</h1>
            <div id="sine" ref="sine"/>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ResizeComponent(Sine);
```

And I have a higher order component like this:

```
export var ResizeComponent = ComposedComponent  => class extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.createDocument();  // undefined
  }

  render() {
    return <ComposedComponent {...this.props}/>;
  }
};
```

How can I call an instance method from the class that is being wrapped from the higher order component?

Comment: Why not just have the componentDidMount call be in the wrapped component?  i.e. `Sine` in this case.

Comment: Are you trying to pass values to `this.createDocument()` from the HOC?  In your example there is no reason why the Sine component shouldn't just have the `componentDidMount() { this.createDocument(); }` in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call an instance method just create a `ref` callback to the wrapped component and access it there.

```
export var ResizeComponent = ComposedComponent  => class extends Component {
  onMounted(node) {
    node.createDocument();
  }
  render() {
    return <ComposedComponent
              ref={(node) => this.onMounted(node)}
              {...this.props}/>;
  }
};
```

However to avoid using `refs` you could also pass a prop to your wrapped `Sine` to decide if you want to call `createDocument()` on `componentDidMount`

Comment: Nice trick! But that works only when the component mounts. It doesn't resolve how to call instance method from higher order component in react.

Answer (score 1):

HOC cannot do that. Yet, in case you want a function from HOC available in the wrapped component, you can passed its through props.

Otherwise, to resolve your case, use inheritance:

```
class ResizeComponent extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount() {
        this.createDocument();
    }
};

class Sine extends ResizeComponent{  
    createDocument() {
        console.log('in createDocument');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="row">
                    <h1>Sine Wave</h1>
                    <div id="sine" ref="sine"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `but those functions must be passed through props` thats not true.

Comment: Ho? Please, provide a fiddle to prove that not true. Thank you :)

Comment: wrong sentence, I should say thats not 100% true, since HOC dont "must" to pass props to the wrapped components, they can add functionality without passing  callbacks, e.g. a HOC that determines if a clicked happened outside of the wrapped component.

Comment: Hum ok I see you're point. I say 'must' by resolving the present case of having a function availablein the wrapped component. I'll edit my post. Thank you